# How to replace all occurrences of a match pattern in a line?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a line like:

```
"[foo] and (foo) along with foofrancis.foo = foo"
```

Where the match pattern `"foo"` is always contiguous to non `a-zA-Z` characters but may occur any number of times in a line.

I want to replace all occurrences of `"foo"` with `"bar"` when foo is not contiguous to an a-z or A-Z character and output a newline.

Where `foo` and `bar` are both variables I am passing in. Sort of like:

```
 foo = "Hello"
 bar = "Goodbye"
 line = "[Hello] and (Hello) along with Hellofrancis.Hello = Hello"
 newline = re.sub(<Unsure what goes here>,line)
 print newline
```

Output:

```
[Goodbye] and (Goodbye) along with Hellofrancis.Goodbye = Goodbye
```

I'm not sure how I configure my `re.sub`

Comment: You mean `newline = line.replace(foo, bar)` ?

Comment: [**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: if its a fixed character string...why are you using regex? Just use [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

Comment: Given `line="HelloGoodbye"`, should `newline` be updated to `"GoodbyeGoodbye"` or remain `"HelloGoodbye"`? In other words, should you take word boundaries into account?

Comment: I realise my lack of clarity. It must be regex since foo may occur as a match contiguous to an a-z or A-Z character. In which case it should not be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

foo = re.escape("Hello")
bar = re.escape("Goodbye")
line = "[Hello] and (Hello) along with Hellofrancis.Hello = Hello"
newline = re.sub("\\b" + foo + "\\b", bar, line)
print (newline)
```

That should do what you are looking for.  re.sub takes requires 3 params.  What you are replacing, to what, and the text.  The \b is a word boundry. notice the Hellofrancis won't change as per your request to contigious.  I also escaped your foo and bar so if the data coming in has regex characters like a period it won't mess with your output.

Comment: This is amazing! I would never have thought to do it this way. Simple and effective. Tried it and it works.